# Read json using c# preferably using newtonsoft

Tags: json, json.net

I have got this below json

```
{"title":"JSON Sample Data","items":[{"name":"text","value":"text data"},{"name":"integer","value":100},{"name":"float","value":5.65},{"name":"boolean","value":false}]}
```

can anyone help me reading it with json.net?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
....

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(myJson);
List<Item> items=data.items;
```

classes

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This Json that spits out changes frequently for reasons my side cannot control.. Assuming it next spits out --------------{"title":"JSON Sample Data","items":[{"name":"text","value":"text data","owner":"John"},{"name":"integer","value":100,"owner":"Rick"},{"name":"float","value":5.65,"owner":"Jane"},{"name":"boolean","value":false,"owner":"Rick"}]}---------- what are the options of reading unstructured data quickly? If you ask me I want to get rid of those classes

Comment: @user7492713 I added  a string owner property.  Now it will be working  for both jsons.